Can't write to /sys/bus/usb/devices/.../power/wakeup as root
Not long ago, I successfully edited the file /sys/bus/usb/devices/.../power/wakeup as explained by the kernel documentation at https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.5/driver-api/usb/power-management.html#the-user-interface-for-dynamic-pm, but now I can't.
I'm getting the error message "Error writing lock file /sys/bus/usb/devices/.../power/.wakeup.swp: Permission denied" despite being root.
I tried with a different device and the same thing happens.
I have not seen a related error message in the log files and apparmor did not block the operation.

Seems the question needs an update and that what you have labeled as an EDIT should be the answer to the revised question.

@David The question still stands. I just found a workaround. But I agree it deserves being an answer.

You can't use nano.
Instead, you execute echo enabled | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/.../power/wakeup or alternatively sudo sh -c "echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/.../power/wakeup" , but the change will only last as long as the device remains connected.
